# blender 2.93 and upbge 0.3 (program crashes and then quits when running simulation with navigation mesh

Tags: mesh

2 scenes (main) and (you lose - return to main)

Three objects (a plain and 2 cubes)
Applied: (Plain - navigation mesh)
(Cube 2 - logic bricks always and steering-pathfinder)
(Run simulation (P) after collision with cube 1, scene switches to - you lose, great so far)
Press mouse click to play again and return to main scene, program crashes and quits.
I have tried with a completely new game setup, but I get the same result, when build navigation mesh is applied.

Comment: 2.93 is still in Alpha state, if you want, your could report your crash here: https://developer.blender.org/

Comment: thank you for your time.